# How to calculate F1 score or accuracy score for model which has training data and testing data stored in two different csv file?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I am new to machine learning field. I am solving a problem statement to predict IPL match winner , for which two csv files are given(trainingdata and testing data in form of two separate csv files).
Training data has around 700 records and testing data has 60 records.
Target variable(winner) is not there in testdf

I tried random forest classifier. Below is code:

```
predictor_var=['team1','team2','city','venue','toss_decision','toss_winner']

outcome_var=['winner']

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

randomForest1= RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)

randomForest1.fit(traindf[predictor_var],traindf[outcome_var])

pred=randomForest1.predict(testdf[predictor_var])
```

So, how can I get F1 score and on submitting above prediction , I am getting following warning:

> UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
> 'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)

Comment: As suggested in the answer, Use zero_division parameter to control this behavior. The main point is ypred may have different labels but there could be labels in y_true which are not predicted atleast once.

Answer (score 0):

This warning occurs because `y_true` contains labels that are not present in your predictions (`y_pred`) like in the example below:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

y_pred = np.ones(10,)
y_true = np.ones(10,)
y_true[0]=0
print(classification_report(y_true,y_pred))
```

You can remove this warning by setting `classification_report` argument`zero_division=1`.

But it is not wise to ignore it as it shows you that there is a problem with your classifier.